# ios MapKit, following a path

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit

I have a path rendering on my map. I have a series of waypoints and I'm simulating movement through them.

When changing the display region it appears that my coordinate when converted to a CGPoint is floorf by Apple's implementation. This causes a very jittery appearance instead of a smooth one.

Is there anyway to get around this?

```
[m_mapView setRegion: MKCoordinateRegionMake(coord, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0, 0))];
```

The map then tries to center on this given point. However the point may not be pixel aligned as can be view by the following function.

```
CGPoint point = [m_mapView convertCoordinate:coord toPointToView:m_mapView];
```

Thus the mapview floors the centerpoint's result to align all pixels for the underlying map.

Comment: which coordinates are you talking about? when you change the map region with `setRegion:animated:` there is no CGPoint involved.

Comment: I updated my question for clarity. Does that help?

Comment: In this special case you can use m_mapView.center

Comment: Are you saying that `CGPoint point`, for example, equals { 122.45, 201.68 }, and it's centering on { 122, 201 }, and that's not good enough?  And, how are you choosing which points to re-center on?  Normally, when I think of "waypoints", those are infrequent locations of interest.  For example, where turns occur.  Are you interpolating yourself to use many, many "waypoints" along the path, then recenter the map really frequently?

Comment: you should use overlays and/or annotations to display the path, then you don't need `convertCoordinate:toPointToView:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make the view larger than the screen to account for the offset and to avoid clipping.

I simulate a point moving along the route and place it using an annotation and then center on that point at 30 frames per second.

Assume coord is the position of the moving point.

```
[m_mapView setCenterCoordinate: coord];

CGPoint p = [m_mapView convertCoordinate:m_mapView.centerCoordinate toPointToView:m_mapView];
CGPoint p1 = [m_mapView convertCoordinate:coord toPointToView:m_mapView];

CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(p.x - p1.x, p.y - p1.y);
CGRect frame = CGRectInset(CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1024.0f, 1024.0f), -50.0f, -50.0f);
frame.origin.x+= offset.x;
frame.origin.y+= offset.y;
[m_mapView setFrame: frame];
```